# slideUp command being ignored, but works in console?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my snippet of code, intended to show the comments of a certain thread that's selected.

```
$('.comments-count').click(function(){
    if(!commentsDown){
        $(this).parent().parent().siblings('.comments').stop().slideDown();
        commentsDown = true;
        currentlyDown = $(this).parent().parent().siblings('.comments');
    }else{
        $(currentlyDown).stop().slideUp();
        var newDown = $(this).parent().parent().siblings('.comments');
        if(newDown != currentlyDown){
            $(this).parent().parent().siblings('.comments').stop().slideDown();
            commentsDown = true;
            currentlyDown = $(this).parent().parent().siblings('.comments');
        }else{
            commentsDown = false;
            currentlyDown = null;
        }
    }
})
```

The line `$(currentlyDown).stop().slideUp();` works if you post it into the console, but for some reason it's ignored in this script. I put in console.log() commands and it showed that it definitely should execute it.

commentsDown and currentlyDown are global variables, initially set to false and null respectively.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/o54h4uap/)'s a JSFiddle. The threads are currently static HTML. As you can see, if you open a thread and then open a different one it works fine, but it doesn't work to close a thread.

Comment: May be the script is executed before your comments has been loaded.

Comment: I've added a JSFiddle to help explain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to reduce your whole block of code to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.comments-count').click(function () {
        $('.comments-count').not($(this)).parent().parent().siblings('.comments').stop().slideUp();
        $(this).parent().parent().siblings('.comments').stop().slideToggle();
    })

    //Log colour pattern
    $('div.event-log-entry:even').addClass('evens');
    $('div.event-log-entry:even .comments-count').addClass('evens');
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/o54h4uap/1/)**

Comment: As a side note, you can also replace `.parent().parent()` by `.closest('div.event-log-entry-wrap')` if you like.

Comment: I really need to stop trying to work on projects at 1am, this is so blindingly obvious now. Thanks very much, j08691!

Answer (score -1):

Add your function inside document.ready tags;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//insert your code here
});
```

For more info. go on this site: 
http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Hope it helps :)

Comment: If you look at the JSFiddle, it's already in a document.ready function.

Comment: Didn't saw your JS Fiddle, my internet is too slow. Sorry. I think you need to use slideToggle for this. I always use accordions and i just use slideToggle. Thanks.